# R - could not find function "parenvs"

Tags: r, devtools

I'm using R 3.1.2 on Windows 64 bit.
After installing devtools (version 1.6.1), I couldn't call parenvs() function.
Here's how I recreate the issue:

> > library(devtools)
>   > parenvs(all = TRUE)
>   Error: could not find function "parenvs"

Did I miss something ?

Thanks
Yusata

Answer (score 6):

Read the [NEWS](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/master/NEWS.md):

> The parenvs() function has been removed from devtools, because is now
>   in the pryr package.

Comment: Thanks Roland, I need to install pryr instead of devtools. It works now. Thanks.